# If I have a home office and report to a main office, what are the travel expense deduction rules?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, employment, expenses

I have a sales job where I have a home office and I report to a main company office twice per week. My job is to visit potential clients and visit/support existing clients. When I visit the main office, I use a satellite common desk. I do not have office space at the main office.

1. Can I claim a home office deduction?
2. What are mileage deduction rules for:

   a. mileage from home office to the main office?

   b. mileage from home office to client's place of business?

   c. mileage from main office to client's place of business?
3. If I take a taxi or subway, what are the fare deductible rules for:

   a. from home office to the main office?

   b. from home office to client's place of business?

   c. from main office to client's place of business?

Comment: How far is your home from the office?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer not sure the distance is entirely important but rather the WHY he has to go to the site, I know people who are "home based" but have to travel to the site and they do NOT get "reimbursed" for travel under the code because of their job duty which means the travel is "expect part of routine job duties" therefore not specially differentiated. Just something to consider as well, so hopefully the OP can shed light on both distance and also reason.

Comment: Part of it is whether it's a requirement of job, or for his own convenience.

Comment: It is necessary to go the main office a couple of times per week for meetings and to go to client's business to meet clients face-to-face.  I am not reimbursed.  It's expected to come out of my commission pay.

Comment: If travel is "expected part of routine job duties" that doesn't mean it shouldn't get reimbursed by the company. If it doesn't get reimbursed then it would be tax deductible. Sounds like a scammy company to me.